# install statsmodel in python3.6.4

Tags: python

I am unable to install statsmodel in python...in Windows10, 64bit

1. I have `python3.6.4 version` updated all modules to latest version
   including `pip`
2. Installed `cython` latest version,
3. Installed `visual studio 14.0`, installed `mingw 64`  with setup
   settings `ver: 7.3.0; Architecture:x86_64; Threads:posix;
   Exception:sjlj; Build version:0`
4. Added `C:\Program
   Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\bin` to
   path in environment variable settings,
5. Copy and pasted `python36.dll` to `C:\Program
   Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.3.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\lib`
6. Added`distutils.cfg` with `[build]; compiler = mingw32; [config];compiler = mingw32` in that `cfg` file. and pasted in lib\distutils\distutils.cfg
7. I used `pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels` to install statsmodel
8. But i get `error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'mingw64' compiler` this error

Could someone help me out to install statsmodel in python3.6.4...

Comment: Why not use a Python distribution like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) or [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/product/canopy/)?

Comment: I have restrictions to use Anaconda or Canopy...